# Looking for a Micro-USB socket with the same external geometry as Mini-USB

Tags: pcb, usb, components, footprint

I'm looking for a Micro-USB socket which has the same external size as a Mini-USB socket. This is to allow us to update some old products to use Micro-USB without us having to modify all the tools which are used to create the plastic housings. I thought that there may be something on the market specifically designed for this purpose. We can update the PCBs to use new solder pad positions without any problem.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered an adapter?

Comment: That's not really the solution we're after. We do supply Mini-USB cables with the older products. The intent behind the update would be for customer convenience.

Answer (score 1):

The connectors are the same size, give or take a half mm.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The total heights are different, but width and distance/height from the pcb would be the same. You can easily drop in a replacement, considering you can replace the pcb landing, and all that would change is a 1.2mm gap between the top of the connector and the hole you have.